# Custom Web Part in fixed height div

Tags: 2013, development, web-part, custom-web-parts

I am developing a web part and it loads correctly, however when it is set to a fixed height a DIV is appearing before my rendered content with a height set that is the same as the fixed height I set for the Web Part.  The DIV still appears when there is no fixed height set, however because it doesn't have a height set it doesn't affect the display.

```
<div webpartid="432f1246-8d45-457f-b383-2dd390cda41f" webpartid2="06f22f6d-6484-492f-b5ae-37e13061736e" haspers="false" id="WebPartctl00_ctl39_g_06f22f6d_6484_492f_b5ae_37e13061736e" width="100%" class="ms-WPBody noindex ms-wpContentDivSpace " allowremove="false" allowdelete="false" allowexport="false" style="height:400px;overflow:auto;">
  <div id="ctl00_ctl39_g_06f22f6d_6484_492f_b5ae_37e13061736e" style="height:400px;">
// My code is rendered here
```

I am rendering the controls to the page by overriding the Render function:

```
protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
  base.Render(writer);
  string Content = RenderSliderItem(GetSliderItems());
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Content))
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine(RenderStyles());
    if (HideNavigation)
      sb.AppendLine(HideNaveBarContent());
    sb.AppendLine(RenderWrapper(SliderWidth, ThemeName.ToString().ToLower(), Content));
    sb.AppendLine(RenderScripts());
    writer.Write(sb.ToString());
  }
}
```

I have read that Render() shouldn't be overridden, however I couldn't work out how to use the CreateChildControls() function.  I am not sure if the content should be rendered within that DIV and using CreateChildControls() will resolve this issue.

Could you please advise how I could go about fixing this so that the rendered content appears at the top of the web part?

This is a Farm Solution for an in-house installation of SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out that the `base.Render(writer);` line was adding the DIV.  Removing this line brought by DIV to the top of the Web Part and fixed the issue.